# Duplicate of Tag Descriptions sourced from other Stacks

Tags: discussion, moderators

Came across a new one today and thought I'd ask the other moderations/community if they know what the rules are on cross posting tag descriptions. The reason I ask is this morning I was doing my review suggested edit tasks and I noticed a user had filled in some tag descriptions, upon checking them if they was duplicate I found they were but from Stack Overflow.

We have the option to reject these tag descriptions if they are duplicate (external source). Is SO or any other stack for that matter an external source? Should these be rejected or approved? Ive searched for help, I'm sure this has been asked elsewhere, if you know please kindly point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 5):

This has been addressed on the main Stack Exchange meta site:

- [Would it be OK to paste content from Wikipedia into a popular empty tag-wiki?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79000/would-it-be-ok-to-paste-content-from-wikipedia-into-a-popular-empty-tag-wiki)
- [What to do about large amounts of plagiarizing in tag wikis?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137799/what-to-do-about-large-amounts-of-plagiarizing-in-tag-wikis)
- [Make rules regarding copying tag wiki content from other websites more explicit](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80351/make-rules-regarding-copying-tag-wiki-content-from-other-websites-more-explicit)
- [Copying tag-wiki text from SO to SF is it (citation needed)?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80392/copying-tag-wiki-text-from-so-to-sf-is-it-citation-needed)

User contributions on StackExchange sites are licenced under the [Creative Commons Share Alike with Attribution 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) license.  It is OK to copy content from a Stack Exchange website and use it elsewhere (including on another Stack Exchange site) as long as you comply with the terms of the content license.  That would include tag wikis.

We should allow copying as long as it conforms to the license terms and the content is appropriate and relevant for this site as well.  That means that each tag wiki should link back to tag wiki on the other Stack site from which it was copied.  If that is not the case, it needs to be fixed (link added or entire tag wiki deleted) and the user warned.

Including links in tag wikis is not ideal.   When possible we should strive to write something original here.   I can see some utility in importing well written tag wikis from other sites when we are missing them.   A copy with a link is better than nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I think that they need to be approved because if they are same... they are same.

Just for example... definition of let's say `wordpress` here and on SO is same or it should be the same.